# How to convert post to Json - Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

I'm trying to convert data from a post to Json formed.

But I still haven't had success.

I tried to do in this format

Unfortunately I couldn't think of anything.

Could anyone help?

Post

```
{'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'AdbaFrsoWeZTnT07m3VjncmYnYHztaQ214qh8AYH2cI40veXfe0dmfSwkI1o2ma1',
 'det[0][CNPJ]': '8768678678678',
 'det[0][UF]': 'SP',
 'det[0][dhEmi]': '2021-07-13T08:26:30-03:00',
 'det[0][nNF]': '8267',
 'det[0][xNome]': 'INDÚSTRIA',
 'prod[0][0][CFOP]': '6102',
 'prod[0][0][NCM]': '84384000',
 'prod[0][0][UF]': 'SP',
 'prod[0][0][aliquotaInterna]': '18',
 'prod[0][0][counter]': '1',
 'prod[0][0][mva]': '34',
 'prod[0][0][tributacaoEstadual]': '7',
 'prod[0][0][vICMSST]': '0',
 'prod[0][0][vICMS]': '25.74',
 'prod[0][0][vIPI]': '0',
 'prod[0][0][vProd]': '367.68',
 'prod[0][0][xProd]': 'FUSO',
 'prod[0][1][CFOP]': '6102',
 'prod[0][1][NCM]': '84384000',
 'prod[0][1][UF]': 'SP',
 'prod[0][1][aliquotaInterna]': '18',
 'prod[0][1][counter]': '2',
 'prod[0][1][mva]': '23',
 'prod[0][1][tributacaoEstadual]': '7',
 'prod[0][1][vICMSST]': '0',
 'prod[0][1][vICMS]': '15.96',
 'prod[0][1][vIPI]': '0',
 'prod[0][1][vProd]': '228.07',
 'prod[0][1][xProd]': 'PORCA',
 'xNome': 'COMERCIAL'}
```

---

View

```
if post:
            import re
            pattDet = re.compile('^([a-zA-Z_]\w+.)\[([0-9_\-][\w\-]*)\]\[([a-zA-Z_\-][\w\-]*)\]$')
            pattProd = re.compile('^([a-zA-Z_]\w+.)\[([0-9_\-][\w\-]*)\]\[([0-9_\-][\w\-]*)\]\[([a-zA-Z_\-][\w\-]*)\]$')
            pprint.pprint(post)

            det = []
            prodtem = []
            count = 0
            for post_name, value in post.items():
                try:
                    det_count = int(pattDet.match(post_name).group(2))
                    if pattDet.match(post_name).group(1) == 'det':
                        det[pattDet.match(post_name).group(3)] = value
                except:
                    pass

                try:

                    if pattProd.match(post_name).group(1) == 'prod':

                        if count == int(pattProd.match(post_name).group(3)):

                            prodtem.insert(count, {pattProd.match(post_name).group(4): value})

                        else:
                            count += 1

                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    pass

            result.append({
                'det': det,
                'prod': prodtem
            })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

many month ago i have create this for django rest framwork, a parser mutli dimensional, source is [here](https://gitlab.com/chernobyl-disaster.org/backend/-/tree/master/lib/parser)
i have adapted the parser for you

```
import re
class ParserMultiDimensional:
    _reg_split = re.compile(r"(\[.*?\])")

    REG_NAME = r"\s*[a-zA-Z_]\w*\s*"
    _reg_name = re.compile(r"^" + REG_NAME + r"$")

    REG_INDEX_LIST = r"\s*(\d+)?\s*"
    _reg_index_list = re.compile(r"^\[(" + REG_INDEX_LIST + r")\]$")  # can be number or nothing

    _reg_index_object = re.compile(r"^\[(" + REG_NAME + r")\]$")  # need to start with char + alpaha

    _reg_list = re.compile(r"^\[" + REG_INDEX_LIST + r"]$")
    _reg_object = re.compile(r"^\[" + REG_NAME + r"]$")

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self._valid = None

    def conv_list_index(self, key):
        ret = self._reg_index_list.search(key).groups()[0]
        if not ret:
            return -1
        return int(ret)

    def conv_object_index(self, key):
        return self._reg_index_object.search(key).groups()[0]

    def conv_index(self, index):
        if self.is_list(index):
            return self.conv_list_index(index)
        elif self.is_object(index):
            return self.conv_object_index(index)
        else:
            return index

    def is_list(self, key):
        if not key or self._reg_list.match(key):
            return True
        return False

    def is_object(self, key):
        if self._reg_object.match(key):
            return True
        return False

    def is_name(self, key):
        if self._reg_name.match(key):
            return True
        return False

    def split_key(self, key):
        # remove space
        key = key.replace(" ", "")
        results = self._reg_split.split(key)
        # remove empty string
        return list(filter(None, results))

    def valid_key(self, key):
        results = self.split_key(key)
        # not result or check first element
        if not results or not self.is_name(results[0]):
            return []
        for r in results[1:]:
            if not self.is_list(r) and not self.is_object(r):
                return []
        return results

    def set_type(self, dtc, key, value):
        index = self.conv_index(key)
        if self.is_list(key):
            if not len(dtc) or index == len(dtc):
                dtc.append(value)
                key = len(dtc) - 1
        elif index not in dtc:
            # TODO dict same as list
            dtc[index] = value
        return index

    def construct(self, data):
        dictionary = {}

        for key, value in data.items():
            keys = self.valid_key(key)
            if not keys:
                raise Exception(f"invalid key {keys}")
            tmp = dictionary
            for curr, nxt in zip(keys, keys[1:]):
                set_type = [] if self.is_list(nxt) else {}
                tmp = tmp[self.set_type(tmp, curr, set_type)]
            self.set_type(tmp, keys[-1], data.get(key))
        self.__validate_data = dictionary

    def is_valid(self):
        self._valid = False
        try:
            self.construct(self.data)
            self._valid = True
        except Exception as err:
            self.errors = err
        return self._valid

    @property
    def validate_data(self):
        if self._valid is None:
            raise ValueError("You need to be call is_valid() before access validate_data")
        if self._valid is False:
            raise ValueError("You can't get validate data")
        return self.__validate_data
```

to use it

```
parser = ParserMultiDimensional(data_query) # add your post data

if parser.is_valid():
    data = parser.validate_data
    # do your things
else:
    print(parser.errors)
```

the result with your data is

```
    {
"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "AdbaFrsoWeZTnT07m3VjncmYnYHztaQ214qh8AYH2cI40veXfe0dmfSwkI1o2ma1",
"det": [
    {
    "CNPJ": "8768678678678",
    "UF": "SP",
    "dhEmi": "2021-07-13T08:26:30-03:00",
    "nNF": "8267",
    "xNome": "INDÚSTRIA"
    }
],
"prod": [
    [
    {
        "CFOP": "6102",
        "NCM": "84384000",
        "UF": "SP",
        "aliquotaInterna": "18",
        "counter": "1",
        "mva": "34",
        "tributacaoEstadual": "7",
        "vICMSST": "0",
        "vICMS": "25.74",
        "vIPI": "0",
        "vProd": "367.68",
        "xProd": "FUSO"
    },
    {
        "CFOP": "6102",
        "NCM": "84384000",
        "UF": "SP",
        "aliquotaInterna": "18",
        "counter": "2",
        "mva": "23",
        "tributacaoEstadual": "7",
        "vICMSST": "0",
        "vICMS": "15.96",
        "vIPI": "0",
        "vProd": "228.07",
        "xProd": "PORCA"
    }
    ]
],
"xNome": "COMERCIAL"
}
```

have fun with it ! ;)

Comment: extremely PERFECT. Wow!!! Thank you very, very much.

Comment: thank you very much for your attention. I made a small change to the Post by adding an extra layer. Then your script said "invalid key []" Where can I adjust this? Below is the example

Comment: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'AdbaFrsoWeZTnT07m3VjncmYnYHztaQ214qh8AYH2cI40veXfe0dmfSwkI1o2ma1',
 'list[0]det[CNPJ]': '8768678678678',
 'list[0]det[UF]': 'SP',
 'list[0]det[dhEmi]': '2021-07-13T08:26:30-03:00',
 'list[0]det[nNF]': '8267',
 'list[0]det[xNome]': 'INDÚSTRIA'
  ...                                              }

Comment: Added a "list" parent key

Comment: Im not on my pc , but parser only work with key in braket "[--key-here-]", so for your key like thst "list[0]det[dhEmi]" change to "list[0][det][dhEmi]" , the outupe like this : "{"list": [ {"det": {"dhEmi": ...}]}"
When a  key is number or empty ( like "[]")is create list , else only word char (a-zA-Z_) is create a dict .

Comment: Thank you again. I will try.